# Deleting files using java

Tags: java

```
    import java.io.*;

public class FileChecker {

   private static final String FILE_DIR = "F:/study/";
   private static final String FILE_TEXT_EXT1 = ".pdb";
   private static final String FILE_TEXT_EXT2 = ".ali";
   private static final String FILE_TEXT_EXT3 = ".txt";
   private static final String FILE_TEXT_EXT4 = ".py";
   private static final String FILE_TEXT_PREFIX1 = "target.";
   private static final String FILE_TEXT_PREFIX2 = "blastOutput.";
   //private static final String FILE_TEXT_PREFIX3 = "1OPL.";

  //public static void main(String args[]) 
   public FileChecker()
   {
/*new FileChecker().deleteFile(FILE_DIR,FILE_TEXT_EXT1);
        new FileChecker().deleteFile(FILE_DIR,FILE_TEXT_EXT2);
        new FileChecker().deleteFile(FILE_DIR,FILE_TEXT_EXT3);
       new FileChecker().deleteFile(FILE_DIR,FILE_TEXT_EXT4);
      new FileChecker().deleteFile2(FILE_DIR,FILE_TEXT_PREFIX1);
        new FileChecker().deleteFile2(FILE_DIR,FILE_TEXT_PREFIX2);
        new FileChecker().deleteFile2(FILE_DIR,FILE_TEXT_PREFIX3);*/
   }

   public void deleteFile(String folder, String ext){

     GenericExtFilter filter = new GenericExtFilter(ext);
     File dir = new File(folder);

     //list out all the file name with .txt extension
     String[] list = dir.list(filter);

     if (list.length == 0) return;

     File fileDelete;

     for (String file : list){
    String temp = new StringBuffer(FILE_DIR).append(File.separator).append(file).toString();
        fileDelete = new File(temp);
        boolean isdeleted = fileDelete.delete();
        System.out.println("file : " + temp + " is deleted : " + isdeleted);
     }
   }
 public class GenericExtFilter implements FilenameFilter {

       private String ext;

       public GenericExtFilter(String ext) {
         this.ext = ext;             
       }

       public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
         return (name.endsWith(ext));
       }
    }

 public void deleteFile2(String folder, String prefix){

     GenericExt filter = new GenericExt(prefix);
     File dir = new File(folder);

     //list out all the file name with .txt extension
     String[] list = dir.list(filter);

     if (list.length == 0) return;

     File fileDelete;

     for (String file : list){
    String temp = new StringBuffer(FILE_DIR).append(File.separator).append(file).toString();
        fileDelete = new File(temp);
        boolean isdeleted = fileDelete.delete();
        System.out.println("file : " + temp + " is deleted : " + isdeleted);
     }
   }
 public class GenericExt implements FilenameFilter {

       private String prefix;

       public GenericExt(String prefix) {
         this.prefix = prefix;             
       }

       public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
         return (name.startsWith(prefix));
       }
    }  

 public void deleteFile3(String ID, String Chain)
 {
     File file = new File(ID+".pdb");
     if(file.delete())
     {
     System.out.println(ID+"deleted");
     }
     File file2 = new File(Chain+".pdb");
     if(file2.delete())
     {
      System.out.println(Chain+"deleted");
     }

 }


}
```

This code is invoked from another class. When run in continuation as several of my codes should be.. it does not delete two pdb files specifically when i try to delete my files of a specific file extension.  I tried closing then them too using file.close() and then deleting them again when the entire file name and extension is know but again to no avail.

```
    String FILE_DIR = "F:/study";
    String FILE_TEXT_EXT1 = ".pdb";
  String FILE_TEXT_EXT2 = ".ali";
  String FILE_TEXT_EXT3 = ".txt";
  String FILE_TEXT_EXT4 = ".py";
    String FILE_TEXT_PREFIX1 = "target.";
  String FILE_TEXT_PREFIX2 = "blastOutput.";
 //  String FILE_TEXT_PREFIX3 = "1OPL.";


new FileChecker().deleteFile(FILE_DIR,FILE_TEXT_EXT1);
        new FileChecker().deleteFile(FILE_DIR,FILE_TEXT_EXT2);
        new FileChecker().deleteFile(FILE_DIR,FILE_TEXT_EXT3);
       new FileChecker().deleteFile(FILE_DIR,FILE_TEXT_EXT4);
      new FileChecker().deleteFile2(FILE_DIR,FILE_TEXT_PREFIX1);
        new FileChecker().deleteFile2(FILE_DIR,FILE_TEXT_PREFIX2);
   // new FileChecker().deleteFile2(FILE_DIR,FILE_TEXT_PREFIX3);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(FILE_DIR+TemplatePDBID+".pdb", true));
    bw.close();
    BufferedWriter bw1 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(FILE_DIR+Template+".pdb", true));
    bw1.close();
    new FileChecker().deleteFile3((FILE_DIR+TemplatePDBID), (FILE_DIR+Template));
```

This is the snippet of the other class which invokes my FileChecker class at the end.

I'm pasting the out I received

```
file : F:/study\1OPL.pdb is deleted : false
file : F:/study\1OPL_A.pdb is deleted : false
file : F:/study\model.pdb is deleted : true
file : F:/study\alignment.ali is deleted : true
file : F:/study\tempAli.ali is deleted : true
file : F:/study\1OPL.fasta.txt is deleted : true
file : F:/study\ModelDescription.txt is deleted : true
file : F:/study\ModellerOutput.txt is deleted : true
file : F:/study\script.py is deleted : true
file : F:/study\target.D00000001 is deleted : true
file : F:/study\target.ini is deleted : true
file : F:/study\target.rsr is deleted : true
file : F:/study\target.sch is deleted : true
file : F:/study\target.V99990001 is deleted : true
file : F:/study\blastOutput.xml is deleted : true
```

please help me with this anomaly.. I am unable to understand why exactly it is skipping the 1st two files in all instances.

Comment: Are there any errors/exceptions?

Comment: no.. it just dosent delete those file when run in continuation.. But if the class is invoked alone.. it deletes them

Comment: The other class writes to `F:/study/Nirmiti/.....` you try to delete in F:/study

Comment: are the two pdb files opened in VisualStudio? Close it before running your program.

Comment: no they are not manually opened at all.. The program accesses these pdb files in the beginning but then closes it. I again closed it in the end before deleting the files.

Comment: If you are using Java 7, try using the java.nio.file classes instead of java.io.File.  In particular, the Files.delete method is declared to throw IOException, so you can catch and print the exception, which should give you some useful information about what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The other class does not write to `F:/study` (or at least the code you showed before editing didn't) where you expect the files, so there are none.

In addition, you might want to use the constructor

```
File(File, String)
```

when going through directory lists, i.e write

```
 fileDelete = new File(dir, file)
```

instead of constructing the name in a StringBuffer.

Comment: Hi Ingo! thanks for your help. But all the files are written in the same location. There was a typing mistake when i first posted the question. All the files deleted are stored in the same location.

Comment: So, do the files even exist? Do the have by any chance some file attributes that prevent deletion? f.exists && f.isWritable should be true.

Comment: Yes these files exist.. I can see these files not being deleted still in my folder location. and yes exists and isWritable is true.

Comment: ANd what happens if you delete the files manually? Just when your program tells you it couldn't? (Do I have to guide you through every step, by the way?) BTW, try this also with del from the command prompt.

Comment: I am able to delete the files normally. I can even delete it from the command prompt. What intrigues me is that there a 3 pdb files so why does it leave the 1st and the 2nd one when i'm trying to delete it programmatic-ally!

Answer (score 0):

Given the code you have written and the fact that other files are being deleted successfully, one can only conclude that there is a permissions or locking issue with the first 2 files that prevents them being deleted. Have you tried to delete them from command line?